# How to remove subarray with a common element in another array in python?

Tags: python

```
ListA = [['abc','15','2021-10-02 08:53:29'],
         ['def','10','2021-10-01 07:52:19'],
         ['abc','15','2021-10-02 09:53:29'],
         ['def','10','2021-10-01 06:52:19'],
         ['gfc','10','2021-10-01 07:52:19']]

ListB = ['abc','def']
```

Since `ListB` has `'abc'` and `'def'`, the script should

1. compare subarrays in array A which have `"abc"`:

   1. find the latest date. eg.`'2021-10-02 09:53:29'`
   2. remove subarray which has "abc" but the date is earlier than the latest date
2. compare subarrays in array A which have `"def"`
   a) find the latest date. eg. `'2021-10-01 07:52:19'`
   b) remove subarray which has `"def"` but the date is earlier than the latest date

The final output should be

```
A = [['def','10','2021-10-01 07:52:19'],
     ['abc','15','2021-10-02 09:53:29'],
     ['gfc','10','2021-10-01 07:52:19']]
```

How to do this in Python?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are very welcome to be here, we love having your here. It's just your question that we are having troubles welcoming, because we are not a code writing service. So you are welcome and we welcome you, please feel that you are welcomed, but your question is going to get closed and deleted.  If you do not abide by these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide what you have already tried and which part you are stuck with

Comment: Also I assume the last sublist is not intended to be a nested sublist with a missing closed bracket so I changed it to be a list of lists

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the array by key and date, then `groupby` and take the item with highest date if key is in ListB else, the whole array. Finally flatten using `chain`:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

list(chain(*([list(g)[-1]] if k in ListB else list(g)
             for k,g in groupby(sorted(ListA, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[-1])), lambda x: x[0])
            )
          ))
```

output:

```
[['abc', '15', '2021-10-02 09:53:29'],
 ['def', '10', '2021-10-01 07:52:19'],
 ['gfc', '10', '2021-10-01 07:52:19']]
```

*NB. this is not preserving the original order of the lists*

#### keeping order

If order is important, it is possible to save it (here using `enumerate`) and to reorder after filtering:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

[
i[1] for i in
sorted(chain(*([list(g)[-1]] if k in ListB else list(g)
             for k,g in groupby(sorted(enumerate(ListA), key=lambda x: (x[1][0], x[1][-1])), lambda x: x[1][0])
            )
          ))
]
```

output:

```
[['def', '10', '2021-10-01 07:52:19'],
 ['abc', '15', '2021-10-02 09:53:29'],
 ['gfc', '10', '2021-10-01 07:52:19']]
```

Comment: @liuxu you can consider marking the answer as accepted if your problem is solved ;)

Comment: Thanks @mozway, but can you explain more about the script? I want to understand more about it :)

Comment: @liuxu what have you not understood? Group by key (second item), if the key is in ListB take the last (most recent) element, else the whole list. Finally, flatten the lists to original format. Let me know if anything is unclear, but the best might be to try running the code from in to out to see the intermediates